# how can I use Cisco ASA 5505 to permit some specific users to access the internet

Tags: cisco-c5500

Please how can I use Cisco ASA 5505 to permit some specific users to access the internet .

Note: I want to allow  5 users to access the internet and block the others.

Best Regards

please see below the configuration,

```
ciscoasa# sh
ciscoasa# sho
ciscoasa# show ru
ciscoasa# show running-config
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.3(1)
!
hostname ciscoasa
enable password 8Ry2YjIyt7RRXU24 encrypted
passwd 2KFQnbNIdI.2KYOU encrypted
names
!
interface Vlan1
 description LAN
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 description INTERNET
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address dhcp setroute
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
```

Comment: Do the users have fixed IP addresses?  Please post your current ASA configuration

Comment: NO they they don't have

Comment: Please add the configuration in your original question (using the code feature of the editor). Further, given the users do not have a fixed / static IP address, how would you like to identify them?

Comment: please see the configuration above

Comment: Can you give the 5 users a fixed ip address, or configure the DHCP server to always give them the same ip address ("reservation")? That would really make it very easy as you would just use those ip addresses in an ACL. If its really not possible to do that, do you have a radius server or an ldap server available (can be an AD server) on which those 5 users have an account or can be given an account?

Comment: Or can you put those 5 users in a different vlan?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of a few possible strategies to achieve the desired result of allowing 5 users Internet access and blocking all others:

1. Configure static IP addresses on the PCs of the 5 users or configure the DHCP server with IP address reservations for those 5 (based on their MAC address, always assign them the same IP address). Then on the ASA you can simply put an ACL on the inside interface allowing only traffic from those 5 ip addresses.
   Note that this is the most basic solution, but:

   - This allows the 5 *PCs* access, not the 5 *users*. So user6 can still access the Internet from user5's PC.
   - It is subject to IP spoofing, i.e. when user6 sees that user5's PC is powered off, user6 can configure user5's IP address on his PC and hence get Internet access.
2. Physically separate the users' PCs in 2 different (V)LANs. E.g. if your current setup has all users connected to a switch (or set of switches) connected to Eth0/1, then unplug those 5 users and plug them into ports Eth0/2-6 and configure those as vlan 3, configure an `interface vlan3` etc., put a blocking ACL in vlan1 and a permissive ACL on vlan3.
   Note that

   - this is still device based, not user based, i.e. this still allows user6 to use user5's PC to access the Internet
   - there are some physical restrictions
   - user6 may potentially unplug user5's cable and plug it into his PC to get Internet access
   - you'll need a new IP subnet and DHCP range (for which the ASA can either be the DHCP server, or DHCP relay to your current DHCP server).
3. Almost the same as #2 but instead of physically separating them, logically separate them on your existing LAN switch(es), i.e. create a new vlan3 on your LAN switch(es), assign the 5 allowed users' ports to that vlan, configure the link between ASA and switch as trunk (and then same as in #2, configure a vlan3 interface and ACL). Same caveats as in #2.
4. Configure [Cut-Through Authentication](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/56421/asa-cut-through-authentication-proxy-configuration-and-examples) which requires users to enter a username and password before they can access the Internet, so in your case you would only create accounts for the 5 allowed users. Note that this is now user-based, not PC-based. So allowed users can log in from any PC in the network or connect to any switchport, prohibited users cannot access the internet no matter where they are (as long as the 5 users keep their credentials secret).
5. Configure [Identity Firewall](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/asa_84_cli_config/access_idfw.html) which integrates with Active Directory, so users no longer have to authenticate to the firewall explicitly as in #4 but this happens transparently, and you create ACLs based on AD usernames.
6. Configure [802.1x on your LAN switch(es)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3650/software/release/3se/security/configuration_guide/b_sec_3se_3650_cg/b_sec_3se_3650_cg_chapter_01111.html), if they support it, and then you get a whole range of additional options, e.g. you can have the switch dynamically change the vlan on the port the user connects to (and then combine that with #3 above) or dynamically create ACLs on the *switch*.

Answer (score 0):

I would either use:

A. Dot1X MAC authentication to allow them out to the specific resources.
b. A network object created on the ASA which included the IP addresses statically assigned or given reservations through a dhcp pool and the desired port numbers along with the direction of travel.
c. A NAT rule making one IP from many (PAT) inserting the dynamic or static IP addresses into one NAT pool and then using this IP address to allow access on port 80 and 443 to the internet.Lastly specify the direction of the rule, inside to outside is what you are looking for in this situation from what I'm reading.

Here is the link to a very good and descriptive articleon Cisco's site involving PAT (port address translation and NAT). It just depends how you want it set, but you have many options.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/118996-config-asa-00.html

Best,